# Express - req.body não acha os dados enviados pelo cliente

Tags: ajax, node.js, express.js

Tenho um pequeno formulário com login e senha cujos dados preciso que sejam enviados para uma rota X via POST. Para isso, usei o AJAX e pra ter certeza de que os dados estavam sendo enviados, usei a função success pra mostrar um log de feedback. O problema, é que na rota responsável por receber esses dados, não consigo acessá-los. Estou usando o Express e até onde eu sei, pra acessar os dados deve-se usar o req.body.nomeDoDado, porém ao fazer isso o valor retornado é undefined. Como posso resolver isso?

**Javascript do cliente para envio dos dados**

```js
$("#btn-signin").click((e) => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const login = $('#loginform').val()
      const password = $('#passwordForm').val()

      await $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8081/Auth/check-signin",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          login: login,
          password: password
        },
        success: console.log('Dados enviados!')
      })

      const res = await apiResponse()

      if (res.errorMessage) {
        alert(res.errorMessage)
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
    }
  })()
})
```

Comment: Caso minha resposta não resolva, sugiro que edite o post incluindo o código do seu back-end. Dessa forma outras pessoas poderão identificar com mais facilidade onde está o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Qual sua versão do Node? Em versões mais recentes, não é necessário utilizar o BodyParser. A configuração que faço em minhas aplicações é a seguinte:

```js
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Como está configurado o seu express?

Você pode usar o [bodyparser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) para poder receber os dados. Você pode aplicar dessa forma aqui:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Com essa config você consegue deve conseguir pegar os dados enviados.

Comment: Eu já estou usando o body parser, aí é que tá.

const BodyParser = require('body-parser')

App.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
App.use(BodyParser.json())